# Are Ruby arrays loaded from YAML files guaranteed to have their order preserved?

Tags: ruby, arrays, yaml, preserve

I've been told that depending on the YAML library used, when a list (not hash!) in a YAML file is translated into a Ruby array, the order is not guaranteed. However, I've not been able to find any evidence of this. So given a YAML file like:

```
letters:
- a
- b
- c
- d
- e
```

After doing `YAML::load File.read('filename')`, I'm always guaranteed to get `{'letters'=>['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}`, instead of some other ordering, regardless of which YAML library I'm using, correct?

Comment: I've never heard that. Lists and arrays are intrinsically ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, order of a sequence is guaranteed.  From the [spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765608) discussion of *unordered* mappings:

> In every case where node order is significant, a sequence must be used.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the Ruby YAML implementation
but a "list" is, by definition, "an ordered collection of values".

And, a YAML list is indeed defined in this way;

```
letters:
- a
- b
- c
- d
- e
```

A quick test;

```
require 'yaml'

results = Array.new(1_000) do
  YAML.load("letters:\n- a\n- b\n- c\n- d\n- e")
end

puts results.uniq
```

Seems pretty safe that it will always be ordered!